# Saving object value of only current instance

Tags: javascript, object

Trying to change a value of an object only for the single instance.

Im trying to make a small library which can a few of the things that jQuery does, just in order to learn the tricks.

I currently have a problem with keeping my elements in the object for usage.

Working example:

```
Brain('#test').html('a'); // this will change the innerHTML of #test with "a".
```

Not working example:

```
var a = Brain('#test');
var b = Brain('#test2');
a.html('a'); // should change content of #test to "a", but changes content of #test2 to "a"
```

My JS:

```
// create the brain function to select elements
var Brain = function(selector, context)
{
    if (typeof context == 'undefined')
        var context = document;

    Brain.elements = context.querySelector(selector);

    return Brain;
};

// set and get innerHTML of element
Brain.html = function(content)
{
    if (typeof content != 'undefined')
        Brain.elements.innerHTML = content;
    return Brain.elements.innerHTML;
};

// testing
var a = Brain('#test');
var b = Brain('#test2');
a.html('a');
b.html('b');
```

My HTML

```
<p id="test">test</p>
<p id="test2">test2</p>
```

#### [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/marktopper/yxjan37y/)

Comment: You're using a function like it was an object.

Comment: Are you looking for javascript OOP? You look quite confused.. Despite the example seems to be partially working, this is not the appropriate way to move on in javascript, at least I don't think this is the proper way to work in such a situation, where you're probably looking for a generic or global object.

Comment: Not sure if you were looking for something like this: -> http://jsfiddle.net/yxjan37y/1/

Comment: @Teemu, the reason I did that is in order to get both functions like `Brain.toJson(object);` and `Brain('#something').html()` to work. So with or without the leading `()` after ´Brain´.

Comment: @briosheje, yes. I am looking to dig into Javascript OOP. Thanks for your fiddle. The only thing is, this way I can not make methods like `Brain.toJson(object)`.

Comment: @Mark: yes, you can, you just have to dig a little bit more into javascript OOP ;). It is not very basic, indeed, but you can actually look further and try to imagine in what way a class can be implemented in javascript.

Comment: @briosheje, my bad. Actually I will be able to create methods for `Brain` (without the `()`). Like `Brain.test = function(){alert('a');};`. This is just what I need thanks.

Comment: Please implement methods using the prototype, like this: `Brain.prototype.functionName = function (valuesyouwanttopassifneeded) { };` Also, you can overrride a function if you need to ;)

Comment: @briosheje Thanks for the note. Just what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome! Have fun OOPing with javascript! Also, if you want to, check this tutorial: http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/ it covers much of what you need to know. For further and advanced notes, feel free to check the **advanced** javascript section in the official MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 0):

Hi i Just gone through your code. the loop is rotating twice and ends at `#test2` id. that means `Brain` contains element of `#test2` that's why second element is changing.
Change code as below it is working

```
var a = Brain('#test').html('a');
var b = Brain('#test2').html('b');
```

Happy codeing

Comment: I am well aware of this fix, but I would like to edit my library in order to work the other way around. Thanks anyways.